# Ruby sort_by array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an array of hashes that I'd like to be able to sort alphabetically on one of the values.

Array of hashes:

```
[{"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"test"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"batch update testing"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"test"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"batch update testing"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"test"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"batch update testing"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"test"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"batch update testing"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"test"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"batch update testing"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"test"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"batch update testing"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"test"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"batch update testing"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>22, "field_string"=>"c next"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>33, "field_string"=>"d next"}]
```

After running sort_by:

```
records.sort_by { |rec| rec[:field_string]}
=> [{"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"test"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"batch update testing"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"test"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"batch update testing"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"test"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"batch update testing"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"test"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"batch update testing"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"test"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"batch update testing"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"test"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"batch update testing"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"test"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"batch update testing"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>22, "field_string"=>"c next"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>33, "field_string"=>"d next"}]
```

It sorts correctly for the field_int column, but I cannot understand why it's not working correctly with the field_string.
If anyone has any ideas I'd really appreciate hearing them.

Thanks!

Comment: `records` sounds like a collection of `ActiveRecord` instances. Why do you have hashes instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keys in your hashes are strings and not symbols.

`records[0][:field_string]` is `nil`

`records[0]["field_string"]` is `"test"`

So your sort is comparing nils to nils, and keeps the original order.

You need:

```
records.sort_by { |rec| rec["field_string"]}
```

It outputs:

```
=> [{"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"batch update testing"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"batch update testing"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"batch update testing"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"batch update testing"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"batch update testing"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"batch update testing"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"batch update testing"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>22, "field_string"=>"c next"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>33, "field_string"=>"d next"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"test"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"test"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"test"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"test"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"test"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"test"},
 {"hidden"=>false, "id"=>"5f898f7784743992f24fcb51", "field_int"=>11, "field_string"=>"test"}]
```

It can be confusing, because [`HashWithIndifferentAccess`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) also exists.

Comment: Yep that'll do it! Thanks for that.